# org-capture-templates stopped working

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have `org-capture-templates` defined as below and until today could capture and log my runs fine, but as of today they've stopped working...

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(;; Computing
        ("c" "Computing")
        ("ce" "Emacs" entry (file+olp "~/org/computing.org" "Emacs")
        "* TODO %t %?\n" :prepend t)
        ;; Exercise
        ("e" "Exercise")
        ("er" "Logging a run" table-line (file+olp "~/org/training/training.org" "Running" "Log")
            "| %t | %? | km | min + s | | |" :prepend t)
        ("ec" "Logging a cycle" table-line (file+olp "~/org/training/training.org" "Cycling" "Log")
            "| %t | %? | km | min + s | | |" :prepend t)))
```

Snippet of my `~/org/training/training.org` is...

```
* Running
** Log
#+NAME: running-log
#+CAPTION: Running Log
| Date             | Route             | Distance | Time         | Pace                          | Notes       |
|------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------|
| <2021-01-03 Fri> | Shorter 12km run  | 12.25km  | 60min + 25s  | 4 min / km + 55.918367 s / km | Less icey!        |
| <2021-01-01 Fri> | Longer 16km run   | 16.22km  | 80min + 03s  | 4 min / km + 56.115906 s / km | Icey!            |
```

...and `~/org/computing.org` is...

```
* Emacs
** TODO <2020-11-11 Wed> vterm only on non-work computers.
```

If I `C-c c` to start `org-capture` and select `[c]... Computing...` `[e] Emacs` I'm prompted for an entry under `* Emacs` in `computing.org` and until today `[e]... Exercise...` `[r]   Logging a run` brought up a blank template like...

```
| <2021-01-03 | <cursor here to start entry> | km | min + s | | |
```

...and I could enter details distance and time, save it and the entry appeared in the `~/org/training/training.org` with the pace calculated.

Now though I'm informed...

```
Capture abort: Symbol's function definition is void: assert
```

Debugging shows...

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture abort: Symbol’s function definition is voi...")
  signal(error ("Capture abort: Symbol’s function definition is voi..."))
  error("Capture abort: %s" "Symbol’s function definition is void: assert")
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

...which doesn't mean much to me.  If I look at the entry under `[C] Customize org-capture-templates` I have...

```
[INS] [DEL] Choice: [Value Menu] Multikey description:
            Keys       : e
            Description: Exercise
[INS] [DEL] Choice: [Value Menu] Template entry:
            Keys           : er
            Description    : Logging a run
            Capture Type   : [Value Menu] Table line
            Target location: [Value Menu] File & Outline path:
            Filename       : [Value Menu] Literal: ~/org/training/training.org
            Outline path:
            [INS] [DEL] Headline: Running
            [INS] [DEL] Headline: Log
            [INS]
            Template       : [Value Menu] String: | %t | %? | km | min + s | | |
            Plist:
            [X] Key: :prepend t
            [ ] Key: :immediate-finish t
            [ ] Key: :jump-to-captured t
            [ ] Key: :empty-lines 1
            [ ] Key: :empty-lines-before 1
            [ ] Key: :empty-lines-after 1
            [ ] Key: :clock-in t
            [ ] Key: :clock-keep t
            [ ] Key: :clock-resume t
            [ ] Key: :time-prompt t
            [ ] Key: :tree-type week
            [ ] Key: :unnarrowed t
            [ ] Key: :table-line-pos String: 
            [ ] Key: :kill-buffer t
            [INS]
```

Which looks fine to my untrained eye.  Reading the `C-h v org-capture-templates` (see also [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements), I don't see that anything has changed since I first wrote this.

I'm running `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.22) of 2020-11-29` (recent compile date is because its under Gentoo). I run Emacs as a daemon and connect a client to it and tried first re-evaluating my `org-capture-template` but with the same result.  I then restarted the daemon and the error persisted.

I don't understand the debugging and why `org-capture` is being called interactively with `nil nil` arguments as I think I have defined the templates correctly and it worked fine until today.  Any insight would be gratefully received.

#### EDIT (2021-01-03) :

After adding `(require 'cl)` as suggested it still errors with the following backtrace...

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture abort: Invalid function: assert")
  signal(error ("Capture abort: Invalid function: assert"))
  error("Capture abort: %s" "Invalid function: assert")
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

#### EDIT (2020-01-04) :

I found things still worked on a laptop, but then updated packages and org-capture broke in the same way there.  The packages updated don't seem related to org but I'm detailing them here for reference...

```
company-20201214.1620
ein-20201217.1508
flycheck-20201214.2154
forge-20201212.905
magit-20201212.929
org-ref-20201126.1924
pass-20190830.2017
projectile-20201214.839
python-mode-20201218.751
pyvenv-20201210.1509
auctex-12.3.1
dash-20201215.59
dash-functional-20201215.40
ess-20201217.1440
git-commit-20201115.2313
helm-20201215.1623
helm-core-20201202.907
ivy-20201217.1559
key-chord-20160227.1238
markdown-mode-20201211.329
mpdel-20201026.1123
transient-20201205.1610
```

Comment: `assert` is defined as an alias to `cl-assert` in `cl.el`. It's not clear who is trying to call it, but `cl.el` has been deprecated since emacs 27.1, so it may be that it used to be loaded but is not any longer. You can try `(require 'cl)` and see if the error goes away, but that is only a stop-gap measure.

Comment: Thanks @NickD I've given that a whirl and it, obviously, reports that its deprecated on loading, trying to capture it errors with `Capture abort: Invalid function: assert`. I find `cl.el` under `/usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp/obsolete/cl.el`, could there perhaps be a something under `org-mode` that relies on this and its worth reporting upstream? Found an [old thread](https://orgmode.org/list/871udr1wer.fsf@bzg.ath.cx/) advising against use of `cl.el`.

Comment: I also see [Org 9.4.2 was released recently](https://orgmode.org/list/87tusmxr8g.fsf@codeisgreat.org/T/#m504663b888722c446e1b06d535bcb8cd5a50b017) and has been merged with Emacs 27, and read elsewhere (a few weeks ago and can't recall where) that 27.2 release is in the offing, may give the new release a whirl.

Comment: I have found custom org-agenda custom templates to be very temperamental over the years. I recommend you always make a backup copy of your .emacs file when you make changes to it. For this I would recommend xah-make-backup.

Comment: Good to hear I'm not alone in experiencing this.  I've kept key files with settings and configuration under Git version control in `~/.config/emacs/` for a few years now.

Comment: assert is a macro not a function I think. This implies the sequence: (1) load cl (2) load whichever lib is using assert *in source form* (3) run your troublesome command. For (2) you must remove the elc files... whichever wherever. Maybe also between 1 & 2 verify eg at scratch buffer that assert exists by doing eg (assert t)

Comment: (2) can also be compile. Which can well be package uninstall-reinstall. Point is that should happen in an environment where assert exists. Also if you follow this route, between 2&3 may be good to restart Emacs daemon. Come to think of it : this kind of debugging would be better/easier in standard (desktop) Emacs if possible. ie switch off and don't use daemon/client till you've sorted this out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Rusi the challenge I have is working out which lib to look at for (2).  I noticed the behaviour occurring again on my work laptop after updating the packages I listed in my second edit but can't for the life of me think why any of those would affect it and don't have time right now to go digging.  I'll report to the org mailing list what I've found though and/or submit a bug report as old thread I found suggests relying on `cl.el` shouldn't be done.